# Light object is NOT seen on the viewport

Tags: lighting

In Blender 3.0, when I add any new light object it is NOT seen on the viewport, as if it does not exist at all. It is only shown in the Outliner. There is no problem with all the other objects. What is wrong with my settings?

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled the Display Overlays button (double sphere icon button on the top right), or that you haven't disabled the lights in the Object Types Visibility panel (also top right, eye icon button)

Comment: Moonboots thank you so much. Long ago I disabled the Light Object Visibility eye icon button and completely forgot it. Thanks to you the issue is resolved. Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled the *Display Overlays* button (double sphere icon button on the top right), or that you haven't disabled the lights in the *Object Types Visibility* panel (also top right, eye icon button):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the viewport objects representing your lights, cameras, or other empty or wire objects are not displaying, you may have disabled the "extras" overlays under your viewport overlays! Let's re-enable this setting:

[image]

[image]

Make sure that the box labeled "Extras" is checked!

[image]

Voila! Your "extra" overlays have been enabled!